# Can APK send command to run dhcpcd through JNI?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I write an android program mydhcp to send command which is run dhcpcd(android default dhcp program):

```
dhcpcd eth0
```

And I write an apk to receive BOOT_COMPLETED action. When received BOOT_COMPLETED, it will call my share library(JNI) libmydhcp.so to control mydhcp. All process are run success, but the dhcpcd start fail.

In my apk's AndroidManifest.xml is already set the uid which is same as system uid:

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

And other uses-permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

The crash point is at main(), it's in the external/dhcpcd/dhcpcd.c

```
pidfd = open(pidfile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_NONBLOCK, 0664);
```

How can modify to solve this problem? Or it is impossible?

Comment: Is there a way to perform these actions via a shell on the device? because then you could execute commands from the app to the shell

Comment: Yes! mydhcp can run in the shell. This pidfile is /data/misc/dhcp/dhcpcd-eth0.pid. And I guess it can't to perform reason is this directory user/group is 'dhcp' not 'system'. Because, it is can work when I change this directory user/group to 'system'. But now I didn't want to change user/group to 'system', can let my apk's get dhcp's uid?

Answer (score 0):

To run commands as root, as per your comment above:

```
public void RunAsRoot(String[] cmds){
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());            
        for (String tmpCmd : cmds) {
                os.writeBytes(tmpCmd+"\n");
        }           
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");  
        os.flush();
}
```

Comment: Dear sbrichards, I got an error: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe).